# Tachanun on Monday and Thursday

Tags: tefilla, calendar, tachanun

Why do we say a longer Tachanun on Mondays and Thursdays compared to the other days of the week?

Comment: Mondays and Thursdays are the two traditional fasting days of Second Temple Judaism. They were most likely chosen due to their being equally distanced from each other and from the Sabbath, so that the pious people might be provided with a constant and balanced opportunity to remember the Torah.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found three reasons in [Aruch HaShulchan 234](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A7%D7%9C%D7%93). Here's my summary:

1. These are days of acceptance (רצון).
   The reason for this being that Moshe
   Rabeinu ascended Mt. Sinai for the
   second tablets on Thursday and
   descended on Monday.
2. These are days of judgment (דין). 
   The courts in heaven and the earthly
   courts convene on these days. The
   sign for this is that the Maadim
   (Mars).
3. Three *zekanim* (scholars) who were
   miraculously saved from a bishop who
   tried to burn them established this
   minhag.

Comment: Summarizing the summarized reasons here would be helpful, specially for those of us who read English but not Hebrew.

Comment: @msh210 Here in Israel it is passed midnight ... I'll try to do just that b"n tomorrow. Thanks for the remark.

Comment: David, what is your basis for saying that the many reasons is an indication of "trouble establishing" as a minhag

Comment: @YDK First, it is very long and repetitive and most people I know are pretty happy when there is any reason not to say it. Second, is that the Beit Yosef had to label one who doesn't say it standing a _poretz gader_.